# Class method does not take implicitly a a pirvate object

Tags: c++

I'm having a bit of an issue, while i was working on an exercise of mine for some reason i got the following error: "'_board' was not declared on this scope" 
As far as i know a class is supposed to take object within them as implicit arguments so why is this happening?

```
enum turn{cross,circle};
class tictactoe_game
{
    public:
    void initialize_board();
    void make_move(int x,int y);
    bool game_won();

    private:
    char _board[3][3];
    turn _player=cross;
    void _display_board();
};

void _display_board()
{
    for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<3;y++)
        {
            cout << "|" <<_board[x][y] << "|";
            //error occurred here and every method that tries to access
            //the class members
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the `_display_board()` implementation has nothing to do with `class tictactoe_game`. You need to specify its scope:

`void tictactoe_game::_display_board() { ... }`

Comment: Thanks i totally forgot about that.